# Если у radio input стоит атрибут checked

Tags: javascript

Если у radio input стоит атрибут checked то выполнить.
Не могу найти нормальный пример в гугле, нахожу только как сделать на нажатие
А мне нужно чтоб, если у радиокнопки уже стоит CHECKED, то выводило например alert или то что у меня выполняло

моя неудачная попытка:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]').on('change',function(){
        var demovalue = $(this).val(); 
        $("div.myDiv").hide();
        $("#show"+demovalue).show();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Вы просили примеры*) Пример раз — https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/f1nebhpx/ , пример двас — https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/fbzxjvgo/ .и пример трис — https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/htbnr75q/ . Начните с последнего, потому что он позволяет вообще не заморачиваться над value и id и добавлять столько вкладок, сколько захочется, переключая их лишь по классам. Недавно здесь был похожий ответ по вкладкам — https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/970962/%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%8B-js/970995#970995

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
```

Спасёт отца русской демократии

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id=1 name="group1" checked>
<input type="radio" id=2 name="group1">
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]').on('change', function(){
        console.log(this.id)
    });
    $('input[checked]').each(function(){
        this.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
    })
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот на чистом JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function () {
let radio = document.querySelector('.radio');
if (radio.checked) alert("Checked!");


radio.onchange = function () {
    if (radio.checked) alert("Checked!");
    else alert("Isn't checked!");
 }
};
```